# Levi Civita covariance and contravariance

Tags: tensor-calculus, covariance

I read some older posts about this question, but I don't know if I'm getting it. I'm working with a Lagrangian involving some [Levi Civita symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol), and when I calculate a term containing $\epsilon^{ijk}$ I obtain the contrary sign using $\epsilon_{ijk}$. I always apply the normal rules: $\epsilon_ {ijk}=\epsilon^{ijk}=1$; $\epsilon_ {jik}=\epsilon^{jik}=-1$ etc. I believed that there is no difference between covariant and contravariant Levi-Civita symbol. What do you know about this?

Comment: You might be interested by formulae $(2.42)$ and $(2.43)$, p.$52$ in this [Sean Carroll Lecture Notes on General Relativity paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9712019)

Comment: Comment to the post (v2): Presumably $ijk$ should be $123$.

Answer (score 7):

Comment to the question (v2): Apart from the issue of various overall sign conventions found in the literature, note that:

1. On one hand, there is the [Levi-Civita **symbol**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol) with upper (lower) indices, whose entries are only $0$s and $\pm 1$s; it is a contravariant (covariant) [pseudotensor **density**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_density), respectively.
2. On the other hand, there is the [Levi-Civita **tensor**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PermutationTensor.html) with upper (lower) indices, whose definition differs from the Levi-Civita **symbol** by a factor of $\sqrt{|\det(g_{\mu\nu})|}$; it is a contravariant (covariant) pseudotensor, respectively.

Comment: I think the most common trend in the literature I see is for the lower-indexed symbol defined with signs given by the parity of the index permutation in the normal way, while the upper-indexed symbol differs from the lower-indexed one by $\mathrm{sgn}(\det g)$. But the OP seems to be in Euclidean $\mathbb{R}^3$ anyway.

Comment: @Chris White: Possibly. Sean Carroll's GR notes agree with your sign convention, cf. Trimok's comment above.

Comment: Hi there, without going into the exact reasons is $\epsilon_ {ijk}=\epsilon^{ijk}=1$ or $\epsilon_ {ijk}=\epsilon^{ijk}=-1$? I'm only asking as I need to perform calculations with the contravariant and covariant forms so I need to know which one is correct, thanks!

Comment: Hi @Electra. Thanks for the feedback. Be aware that different authors might have different conventions.