# Confusion on differential geometry notation

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

Following the [textbook](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-04260-8) of Goeffrey Compère, I am confused with the notation on $p$-forms. He says: "A general $(n-p)$-form is written as boldface $X=X^{\mu_1\dots \mu_p}\sqrt{-g}(d^{n-p}x)_{\mu_1\dots \mu_p}$, developed in the base
\begin{align}
(d^{n-p}x)_{\mu_1\dots \mu_p}=\frac{1}{p!(n-p)!}\varepsilon_{\mu_1\dots\mu_p\nu_{p+1}\dots\nu_n}dx^{\nu_{p+1}}\wedge \dots\wedge dx^{\nu_n}\,."
\end{align}
The latter is defined in the Hodge dual basis? Why one aims to use this notation and not the standard one (e.g., Nakahara)? Seems complicated for something that could be very simple: To define $p-$forms.

Comment: Rather than Hodge dual I suspect that this convention must be related to [tensor densities](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/284285/304394).