# Is Levi cita tensor an invariant in curved space?

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, curvature

The Minkowski metric and Levi cita tensor is an invariant quantity in Euclidean flat space. But in curved space metric tensor varies.  Analogous to it, is the Levi cita tensor varies in any  Non-Euclidean space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On an arbitrary pseudo-Riemannian manidold, the Levi-Civita tensor is a pseudotensor while Levi-Civita symbol is a pseudotensor density. See e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/284057/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/123231/2451) related Phys.SE posts.

For a generic coordinate system $x^{\mu}$, the corresponding Levi-Civita tensor components depend on $x^{\mu}$, if that's what you're asking.